# C# How to show list of objects properties as comma delimited string

Tags: c#

Let's say I have objects like this:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyCars
{
    public List<Car> Cars{ get; set; }

    public string GetCars
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Cars != null ? string.Join(", ", Cars.Select(x => x.Name)) : "N/A";
        }
    }
}
```

If my List has 3 cars with Name property set to "Honda", "VW", "GMC"

how do I convert that list to string to show the Name of each car in the list as comma separated:
Honda, VW, GMC

I am trying to link this in my XAML as:

```
<TextBlock Name="txtCarNames" Text="{Binding Path=MyCars.GetCars}"/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use LINQ to select the desired property, then the `string.Join` method to flatten the list.

```
var cars = new MyCars { /* populate the inner List<Car> */ };

var flatList = cars.Cars != null ? string.Join(", ", cars.Cars.Select(x => x.Name)) : "";
```

Also, you can't have the class and the property both named `Cars`... you'll have to rename one.

Comment: What if Cars is null?  Thanks

Comment: Thank you Grant, ... Interesting.  That is exactly what I am doing but I am still seeing incorrect output.  I updated my question to show what I am doing

Comment: @dbnex14 show us the incorrect output(e.g. exceptions?), "seeing incorrect output" will not help.

Comment: No exceptions, it just shows nothing (empty string) if Cars == null (but it should show "N/A"); otherwise, it shows "N/A" (insterad of comma-separated list of Names).  It is almost as it is reversing the ?: operator.

Comment: Cant figure out what is it.

Comment: @dbnex14, maybe your `Cars` list is an empty list?

Comment: I am checking for both null and Cars.Count != 0

Comment: @GrantWinney I wonder if this has something with the fact that I have 2 getters in MyCars as visible from my original question above?